# Server 2012 Essentials Repair backup database

Tags: essentials-2012, windows-server-essentials

I am new to server 2012 and consistency getting an error that a client computer backup contains errors that must be resolved.  I follow the steps in the dashboard to repair the backup database and get an error in the repair wizard so now i am not sure what i should do to fix these errors.  I tried removing an old computer from my devices in the dashboard and cannot remove it from the server.

Comment: So what are the errors you're getting?

Comment: When removing the computer it says to cancel all scheduled backups before i can remove it, i have turned backing up of the client machines off unless i would need to turn it off elsewhere.  Also when running the backup repair i get an unknow error prevented the backup repair process from starting.  Make sure all services are running then try again.